# Imagine the Moon takes 5000 Years to fall on Earth, what power does it bring? Is the flux of power higher than the one received by the Sun?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, planets, moon

Imagine the Moon takes 5000 Years to fall on Earth, what power does it bring? Is the flux of power higher than the one received by the Sun?

I would like to know which formula I can use, do I need to consider Ep=G*m1*m2/r ? How do I take into account the time of 5000 years ?

I look for a solution "simple" as in a Fermi Question but also for a more rigorous solution.

This post has already looked for a similar question : [How much force would it take for you stop the Moon from crashing into the earth once it has started to fall?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232563/how-much-force-would-it-take-for-you-stop-the-moon-from-crashing-into-the-earth) 
It gives an idea of the Orbit energy of the moon : 7*10^(28) but how to relate this to fact that distance drops to zero and that it is very slow, it takes 5000years. 
To compare it to the sun, I have found that 1 year of Sun gives ~ 4*10^(24) J to the earth, so 2*10^(28)J for the period.

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would take:

You have the gravitational energy at the current orbital distance; and some different energy when you are at the surface of the earth. Divide it by time to get power. Divide by area to get flux.

Note that this assumes that the moon is falling to earth this entire time, and that a region the size of the moon is absorbing the power all that time (basically, if there were sticks supporting every part of the moon, and friction at the bottom of the stick was capturing the energy, how much heat would you generate per unit area; or how much power could you generate).

I will let you do the math.